# Http File upload - Files over 25mb fail - PHP uploading script

Tags: php, html, http, post, upload

I've been banging my head against this for 20+ hours now I would really appreciate some help!

I have simplified the problem here so the code is very simple. Basically this upload script works perfectly until I try to upload a file bigger than 25MB then it fails. PHP gives no errors.

**index.htm**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploaded/";
$target_path = $target_path.basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
/***/highlight_string(print_r($_FILES, true)); //check array

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

**php.ini**

```
[PHP]

post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

My host informed me that the upload limit on the server is 32MB. Ran phpinfo() & the variables in the ini are being changed. It is not a timeout issue (ran a 16mb upload when downloading a file - it took several minutes longer than the 25MB upload but still worked).

I have been spittin out the $_Files array as a string for error checking, heres what I get when it fails:

```
Array
(
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => 30.tif
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 7
            [size] => 0
        )

)
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

Any ideas? Tried it on different servers with the same problem.

Comment: The script works fine on my localhost, here's how a succesful upload looks like:

Array
(
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => 30.tif
            [type] => image/tiff
            [tmp_name] => C:\Program Files\xampp\tmp\php21A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 29972100
        )

)
The file 30.tif has been uploaded

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), it failed to write files to disk.  Can you check quota/disk space/etc.?

Comment: Yep, checked all that, got tons. It's a head scratcher.

Answer (score 0):

[memory_limit](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) might also restrict the size of uploadable files.

Comment: Tried this already. I'm currently running another test - just in case. Thanks.

Comment: No difference :-( I set it to "memory_limit = -1", it is set pretty high by default on my server - "128M".

Comment: did you check that your server used those settings? those attributes might be restricted. have a look at phpinfo()

Comment: Yep, The server is updating using my local php.ini settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your error don't is for the size, the error code 7 is because the file "can't be save in the disk."

to more errors read: [Upload code errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Try change the directive "upload_tmp_dir" in php.ini file and check if is allow the upload of file: 'file_uploads = On'.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but these are set correctly - it is only files over 25MB that have a problem. No file would upload if these were not set.

Comment: can be a hosting limitation, if your have a vps or dedicated, check the syslog for a phplog or apache logs.

Comment: I'm on shared so I can't check the logs, my host assures me there is only the apache 32mb limit. They say they did their own test on my domain & it worked fine - they got all cagey when I asked them to send me the script they used though.

Comment: Guided by the error code, we can not assume anything other than a hosting problem. Do not think you can do more on our side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I'm sure now that it is a host problem, not a problem on my end - even though I've tried it on several hosts - I think it's pretty common for http post to be limited to around 25MB.

I have now set my uploader to take a maximum file size of 20MB, that should make it pretty safe on most hosts.